# Headless/SXA/NextJS - Add site module is not showing up my newly created headless module

Tags: sxa, jss, sxa-jss

We are using Sitecore-10.3/Headless/SXA/NextJS.

Trying to add a new custom SXA headless module to my headless-SXA website but the newly created module is not showing up.

### Steps to reproduce

1. Create a new module using the "Add module" option in `/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature`.

[image]

2. Post this include some renderings by the options add/clone rendering as per your wish.
3. Now try to add this new custom module to your headless-SXA site. Using the script "Add site module".

[image]

4. Expectation is to show the newly created custom headless module but this is not showing the new custom headless module.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is happening because of your custom module site setup root is using a template from "Experience Accelerator", instead of "JSS Experience Accelerator". Follow the steps to fix this

1. Go to your modules, where you created them. In my case `/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature/YourSite/CustomModule/Headless CustomModule Site Setup`.
2. Check the template used. It pointing the legendary "Experience Accelerator".
   [image]
3. This should be corrected. `Configure => Change` your template like below,
   [image]
4. Now try to install module to your headless-SXA website. It will show your custom module.

> Note: This issue is applicable for `Tenant setup` as well. You should change this template in your module `/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature/OMNIA/Headless Experience Accelerator/HeroBanner/HeroBanner Tenant Setup`

Comment: Thanks @Andi AR,
I was facing the same issue. and that solution worked for me!!